# Install Imagick for PHP and Apache on Windows

Tags: php, windows, imagick

Steps I've taken so far:

1. I have installed Imagick on my Win7 machine, and it's installed and running properly via command line.
2. I've extracted the contents of php_imagick-3.1.2-5.6-ts-vc11-x86.zip available [here](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/3.1.2/) into my \PHP\ext directory.
3. Enabled the imagick.dll in php.ini
4. Rebooted...
5. No errors when starting Apache.
6. I'm still getting the `Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found` error when I try to run a script that uses Imagick.

Current Versions:

- Windows 7 x64
- Apache 2.4.10 x86 VC11 (from Apachelounge)
- PHP 5.6.3 x86 VC11 TS (from windows.php.net)
- ImageMagick 6.9.0-0 Q16 x86 (from imagemagick.org)
- Imagick DLL php_imagick-3.1.2-5.6-ts-vc11-x86.zip (from [here](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/3.1.2/))

I was running an older version of PHP and had Imagick working fine with that, then I updated PHP (and the Imagick DLLs along with it) and now I can't seem to get it to work.

Looking at `phpinfo( )`, I don't see Imagick listed there, so it doesn't seem to be loading the module at all. Which is weird, because I'm not getting any errors when starting Apache.

I've tried just about every write-up and walkthrough for installing Imagick for PHP on Windows, but they seem to all be written for older versions of PHP.

Can somebody help me get this installed and running? It seems like it's just missing one simple step that I can't seem to figure out. If you need any more info, please ask. I'll get you whatever I can to help.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**EDIT:** This procedure works with Windows 7 - 10 and all versions of PHP as well.
**Unofficial sites may be discontinued or later be altered to contain malicious code instead. Please use caution when using any recommended links or mirrors other than the official ImageMagick, PECL, or PHP sites provided in comments or other answers.**

I was unable to get Imagick Working with PHP using an older release of ImageMagick as in the originally accepted answer and it was difficult to find mirrors with the exact ***safe binaries*** needed *(the binaries on the mirror in the originally accepted answer downloaded as different versions than listed)*

> In all of the steps below, be sure to match your PHP architecture (x86/x64 and NTS/TS) to the binary's architecture. If you are using PHP x86 - replace the x64 version of the downloads with the x86 (or 32bit) version. The same applies to Thread-Safe (TS) and Non-Thread-Safe (NTS) versions of PHP.

### PHP Imagick Extension

1. Navigate to https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick
   and download the latest DLL **`(3.3.0RC1)`** at time of this answer.
   [image: Imgur]
2. Extract **`php_imagick.dll`** to **`D:\php5.6\ext`**
3. Extract all **`CORE_RL_*.dll`** files to **`D:\php5.6`** -
4. *Ensure **`D:\php5.6`** is already added to the `PATH` of your system environment variables*
5. Add **`extension = php_imagick.dll`** to **`D:\php5.6\php.ini`**
6. Restart Apache, PHP-FPM, or PHP Built-In Web Server
7. Check `phpinfo();` to ensure the module is installed correctly [image: Imgur] *Note the highlighted ImageMagick version* **`(ImageMagick 6.9.1-2 Q16 x64)`** *and the missing supported formats*

### ImageMagick Binary

1. (1a) Download and install the matching version of ImageMagick to **`D:\php5.6\bin`** from https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php - Ensure that the `Add Path to Environment Variables` option is checked or manually add it [image: Imgur]
2. (1b) Alternatively download the [PECL dependencies](https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps/) for your version of the Imagick PECL extension, see below for more details.
3. Load a command prompt *(run as administrator which forces the system path variable to refresh)* and ensure `convert --version` displays the correct version [image: Imgur]
4. Delete the previously extracted **`CORE_RL_*.dll`** files in **`D:\php5.6`** *(they will be loaded via ImageMagick path - otherwise your PHP installation may become unstable with the PECL dlls)*
5. Restart Apache, PHP-FPM, or PHP Built-In Web Server
6. Check `phpinfo();` to ensure the module is still installed correctly and is now loading the Imagick supported formats [image: Imgur]

### Imagick PDF as Image Support - Ghostscript (optional)

1. Optionally download and install Ghostscript to **`D:\php5.6\bin`** to be able to convert PDFs to images from http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghostscript/ *be sure to match the architecture for your installation*

---

I did not need to add `MAGICK_HOME` for Imagick to work using the PHP Built-In Web Server or CGI, but may be required for Apache using `mod_php`. See the **Special Considerations** section below for additional details.

---

### PECL Imagick Dependencies (1b)

You can alternatively download the required ImageMagick version dependencies and extract the `exe` and `dll` files from within the `bin` directory directly into your **`D:\php5.6`** directory.
The dependencies can be found on PECL website http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps/

> Using the PECL dependencies removes the need to directly download and
> run the matching ImageMagick version installer from the vendor's website.

*With the PECL dependencies method there were issues with excluded files needed for PDF conversions using GhostScript.*

---

### Special Considerations

Be sure the user running PHP has permission to execute `convert`. This should be inherited via `D:\php5.6\bin` but in case you chose to install to `C:\Program Files`. you may have issues due to its restricted permissions.

Be sure to rearrange your `PATH` System Environment Variable so that `%SystemRoot%\system32\convert.exe` does not override the `D:\php5.6\bin\convert.exe`.
By adding your PHP path to the left of system32, like so: **PATH: `D:\php5.6\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;...`**

This will force your system to look for executable files within `D:\php5.6\bin` prior to `%SystemRoot%\system32`

*Replace `D:\php5.6\bin\convert.exe` with the path to where you installed ImageMagick or the path to where `convert.exe` is located*

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723564.aspx#XSLTsection127121120120

Comment: Thanks for this. I have recently upgraded to 8.1 and was dreading installing imagick. I'll try this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Wow. I worked through dozens of tutorials and this one did it for me.

Comment: Just ran through this, and it worked beautifully. Thank you!

Comment: The only change I had to make was that the version of ImageMagick that was required was not available on the main ImageMagick website, but was available through a site that hosts older versions: http://ftp.sunet.se/pub/multimedia/graphics/ImageMagick/binaries/

Comment: Thank you, very detailed and usable information. +1!

Comment: Thanks a lot.You jst saved my day

Comment: 9. Delete the previously extracted CORE_RL_*.dll files in D:\php5.6 (they will be loaded via ImageMagick path - otherwise your PHP installation may become unstable with the PECL RC dlls)      Mithun: I missed this one.

Comment: @vaso123 You would use the latest libraries available relevant to your version of PHP. as stated in the post (big yellow box at top). Follow the steps to determine which version of `ImageMagick` binary your `PECL extension` requires. Simply replace the DLL with the newest DLL from PECL. EG: `7.1 Non Thread Safe (NTS) x64` for `3.4.3RC1` The steps are the same for any version of PHP.

Comment: @fyrye Problem is not this. Problem is, that first you download the pecl extension. With this, you can determine what version of ImageMagick you need. Since this step, you did not downloaded any ImageMagick binary. And here comes the problem. Latest PHP 7.1, latest 3.4.3RC1 pecl needs ImageMagick 6.9.3-7 Q16 x64 what is an older version than latest downloadable ImageMagick binary. And you won't find anywhere this installer, and ftp.sunet.se is not available anymore.

Comment: Correct, I do link to the `dependicies` that PECL compiles against  http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps/ that can be used until a new version is compatibile. Linking to an unofficial third-party website is not a solution for PECL not being up to date with the latest ImageMagick binaries. I would be held liable to maintain the link and for any viruses their downloads may contain. Instead I suggest submitting a request to PECL to compile against the latest binary. Otherwise the PECL library will catch up with the latest ImageMagick release.

Comment: You sir, deserve a 

Comment: For anybody still looking for older binaries, a simple Google search will lead you to a few mirrors that still have older versions of ImageMagick. e.g.- http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/ImageMagick/binaries/ as stated earlier.

Answer (score 8):

I finally got it working, here is what I had to do:
(referenced from http://refreshless.com/blog/imagick-pecl-imagemagick-windows/)

1. Install an older version of ImageMagick (6.7.7-5 Q16) available from [this website](http://ftp.sunet.se/pub/multimedia/graphics/ImageMagick/binaries/).
2. Install the PECL Imagick DLL files (php_imagick-3.1.2-5.6-ts-vc11-x86.zip) downloaded from [this webpage](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/3.1.2/), putting the `php_imagick.dll` file in the PHP `ext` directory, and the `CORE_RL_*_.dll` files in the Apache `bin` directory.
3. Add an Environement variable called `MAGICK_HOME` to the machine, with the value of `[ImageMagick install dir]\modules\coders`.
4. Restart apache and check `phpinfo( )`.

If this doesn't work for you, try different versions of the ImageMagick binaries, and different versions of the PECL libraries.

Comment: Is the MAGICK_HOME really needed? Didnt found it in the source https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick

Comment: It's using an older version of ImageMagick, so I'm assuming that it is needed. I haven't tried it without, though, so I can't be certain. I know this method works for me.

Comment: I successfully installed imagick without MAGICK_HOME now. Just use the deps from php and all is fine http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps/

Comment: 2018 approves this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that worked on 3 different windows installations (2 Windows 7 and 1 Windows 8.1) is to combine:

**ImageMagick-6.7.9-10-Q16-windows.exe** with

**xampp-win32-1.8.3-5-VC11-installer.exe**.

Of course you will have to **add the php_imagick.dll** to the php/ext folder and also **add extension**  php_imagick.dll to php.ini. 
**Restart** apache after you do all of the above and if it complains about missing stuff, restart your computer.

Comment: Do note that you may have permission issues if installing ImageMagick in Program Files. The instructions I provided are synonymous with these. (I tested with xampp/wamp as well). Just match the x64 or x86 of ImageMagick and PECL extension versions with the architecture and version of PHP you installed. The main issue is that ImageMagick does not archive its binary releases. So it makes ImageMagick difficult to match up with past versions of PHP and the PECL extension.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download proper extension version from
   http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/ I picked
   3.1.2 which is the latest non-beta at this time

   - Unzip and copy php_imagick.dll to PHP ext folder
   - add  [PHP_IMAGICK] extension=php_imagick.dll    to php.ini
   - Download recommended Imagick version and install from: [Link](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)    ( I
     chose to have C headers and also COM objects during installation)
   - Restart apache
   - Check phpinfo() for Imagick section... there it is!

Answer (score 0):

**Here's how I solved it**

I had really struggled with all these answers. Looking back I realised most of them are correct except they leave out some **very fine** details that are crucial.

**1).** First and foremost, before you start downloading any libraries or DLLs you want to start with your **php_info** to find out these three very important parameters.

Run the PHP_Info and check:

> 1. Architecture : x86 or x64. Your computer might be x64 but your php is running on x86 so don't assume
> 2. Thread Safety : yes or no. Also very important.
> 3. Your PHP Version

**2).** Download ImageMagick from: https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps/. 
    My computer is x64 but my php is running x86 so I downloaded ImageMagick-7.0.*-*-vc*-x86.zip

**3).** Unzip and copy all DLLs from the unzipped bin subfolder to the Apache bin directory. It's a bunch of CORE_RL_*.dll and IM_MOD_RL_*.dll plus a few other DLLs. In my case, [zippeddownload]/bin/* ->copied to -> C:\Xampp\apache\bin

**4).** Go to http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick. You can select the zip link or just the DLL link. I prefer the DLL link. In my case I selected latest version 3.4.3. Which then took me to https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick/3.4.3/windows.
Here we have to make another careful choice

1. My php version is **PHP 5.6**
2. Thread Safety is **enabled**
3. Architecture php is running on is **x86**
4. So I took **5.6 Thread Safe (TS) x86**

**5).** Unzip and copy "php_imagick.dll" to the php **ext** folder. And all other DLL files to the php folder

**6).** Using an editor open **php.ini**. Search for "extension=" and add this line **extension=php_imagick.dll** as one of them.

**7).** Restart Xampp/Wamp or just restart Apache and run PHP_INFO again. Imagick should display. If you still can't see it refer to this link http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setup.php#119084

**Bonus tip:** You might need to download **visual c++ 14 runtime**. From this link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads I chose the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

1, First download right version php_imagick package depending on your situation,  I use php_imagick-3.4.3-7.1-ts-vc14-x64.zip from:

https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/imagick/3.4.3/php_imagick-3.4.3-7.1-ts-vc14-x64.zip

2, Then unzip php_imagick-3.4.3-7.1-ts-vc14-x64.zip to C:/php_imagick folder

3, Next add extension=C:/php_imagick/php_imagick.dll in php.ini

4, Now add *.dll (except php_imagick.dll) to your apache vhost file, for example:

```
# enable imagick start ===========
SetEnv MAGICK_HOME "C:/php_imagick" 

LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/CORE_RL_bzlib_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/CORE_RL_cairo_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/CORE_RL_exr_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/CORE_RL_glib_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/CORE_RL_jp2_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/CORE_RL_jpeg_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/CORE_RL_lcms_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/CORE_RL_librsvg_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/CORE_RL_libxml_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/CORE_RL_lqr_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/CORE_RL_magick_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/CORE_RL_Magick++_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/CORE_RL_openjpeg_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/CORE_RL_pango_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/CORE_RL_png_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/CORE_RL_tiff_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/CORE_RL_ttf_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/CORE_RL_wand_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/CORE_RL_webp_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/CORE_RL_zlib_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/FILTER_analyze_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_aai_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_art_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_avs_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_bgr_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_bmp_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_braille_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_cals_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_caption_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_cin_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_cip_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_clip_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_clipboard_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_cmyk_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_cut_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_dcm_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_dds_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_debug_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_dib_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_djvu_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_dng_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_dot_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_dps_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_dpx_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_emf_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_ept_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_exr_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_fax_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_fd_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_fits_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_fpx_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_gif_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_gradient_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_gray_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_hald_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_hdr_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_histogram_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_hrz_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_html_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_icon_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_info_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_inline_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_ipl_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_jbig_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_jnx_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_jp2_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_jpeg_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_json_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_label_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_mac_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_magick_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_map_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_mask_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_mat_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_matte_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_meta_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_miff_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_mono_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_mpc_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_mpeg_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_mpr_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_msl_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_mtv_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_mvg_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_null_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_otb_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_palm_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_pango_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_pattern_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_pcd_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_pcl_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_pcx_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_pdb_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_pdf_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_pes_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_pict_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_pix_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_plasma_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_png_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_pnm_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_preview_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_ps_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_ps2_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_ps3_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_psd_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_pwp_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_raw_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_rgb_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_rgf_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_rla_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_rle_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_scr_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_screenshot_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_sct_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_sfw_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_sgi_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_sixel_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_stegano_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_sun_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_svg_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_tga_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_thumbnail_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_tiff_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_tile_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_tim_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_ttf_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_txt_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_uil_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_url_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_uyvy_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_vicar_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_vid_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_viff_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_vips_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_wbmp_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_webp_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_wmf_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_wpg_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_xbm_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_xc_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_xcf_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_xpm_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_xps_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_xtrn_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_ycbcr_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/IM_MOD_RL_yuv_.dll"
LoadFile "C:/php_imagick/ImageMagickObject.dll"

# enable imagick end ===========
```

5, last restart apache

Answer (score -1):

**How to install ImageMagick module for PHP 5.6.8 . X64 . TS (Theard Safe) version.**

**General information**

1. **System :** Windows 10 x64
2. **Server Apache :** 2.4
3. **PHP Version :** 5.6.8

---

**Step 1**

---

**1.** Filename : `ImageMagick-6.7.7-5-Q16-windows-x64-dll.exe`

**2.** Download :https://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/ImageMagick/binaries/ImageMagick-6.7.7-5-Q16-windows-x64-dll.exe

**3.** Install it (Don't touch nothing, just click next...next..)
After install, go to command prompt (CMD.exe) and write : `convert --version` If in output you can see like `Version: ImageMagick 6.9.1 ....` (It Works!)

**4.** Done

---

**Step 2**

1. Filename: `php_imagick-3.2.0b1-5.6-ts-vc11-x64.zip`
2. Download:
   https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/3.2.0b1/php_imagick-3.2.0b1-5.6-ts-vc11-x64.zip
3. Extract archive
4. **IMPORTANT !** Copy from extracted archive all files with prefix **CORE_RL(...).DLL** to your Apache **BIN** folder, for example : **C:\Apache2.4\bin**, after, find in extracted archive **php_imagick.dll** file and copy it to PHP **extension** folder, for example : **C:\php5.6.8\ext**
5. Open your **PHP.INI** file, find line `;extension=php_imagick.dll` and just remove (`;`)
6. Save it
7. Done

**How to check is it works ?**

1. Open command promt (CMD.exe)
2. Type, for example: `C:\php5.6.8\php.exe -m`
3. If you can find in output list, name : **Imagick**, when, it works !
4. Or you can check it via `phpinfo();` function