# Installing Imagick for PHP 5.6.3 and Apache 2.4 on Win 8.1

Tags: xampp, windows-8.1, imagick, pecl

I followed the instructions from this post ["https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27193631/installing-imagick-for-php-5-6-3-and-apache-2-4-on-win-7"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27193631/installing-imagick-for-php-5-6-3-and-apache-2-4-on-win-7). The only difference is that I'm on a Windows 8.1.

But I keep getting a warning with "PHP Startup:" from the apache when starting it. The extension does not show up in the phpinfo()