# ImageMagick number of supported formats: has showing value 0

Tags: php, windows, imagick

I am using PHPv5.6 I am trying to install imagic library on my window7(32bit) on xampp server.
To install it I followed all the steps showing on this link-
[Install Imagick for PHP and Apache on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27193631/installing-imagick-for-php-5-6-3-and-apache-2-4-on-win-7)

But I have stuck on its step14. I am not getting any **0** values in **ImageMagick number of supported formats.** and getting no values in **ImageMagick supported formats**.

I dont know What I am missing there. Can anyone help me sought out this problem.

Answer (score 5):

This is a common problem when you have downloaded a version of Imagick that was compiled against a different version of ImageMagick than the one you are trying to run it with.

Try downloading both Imagick and ImageMagick from the same place e.g.

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps/
http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/

Comment: Yes, if you install Imagick on your system from http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps/ and use the PHP extension at http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/, it will work. The important thing is to make sure the Imagick version reported by the PHP extension matches the one you use on your system.

Comment: Don't forget to copy the files in the bin folder of ImageMagick to the root folder, this saved me from 9 hours of internet surfing.

Comment: how one will find out which version of imagick ws compiled against which version of ImageMagick? means i have imagick module version 3.4.3 imagick compiled with image ImageMagick version 6.9.3-7 x86 are they compatible?