# Unable to install imagick

Tags: php, windows, imagick

I found tons of instructions, how to install Imagick on windows. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27193631/installing-imagick-for-php-5-6-3-and-apache-2-4-on-win-7) is a very good and detaild explanation.

I am following the instructions. So, first, download the latest DLL from PECL. Copy the `php_imagick.dll` to the extension dir, copy the `_CORE*` libraries to PHP root directory, and it shows me the following version: `ImageMagick 6.9.1-2 Q16 x64 2015-04-14`

Wow, great, now I have nothing to do just install this exe.

Oh, wait...

There are no installer like this. And the problems starts here. Of course, I've tried to download and install the latest installer, installed it, set the environment variables, but it always says something about entry points.

I don't know why Imagick guys removes the releases from their ftp, I think this is a very bad behaviour. Can not access from archive too.

So I am unable to installing the Imagick.

Can anybody help me with this version of installer, or give me a step-by-step instruction, how to install this Imagick for Windows 10, 64bit for Apache 2.4.2 64bit, and PHP 5.6.5 64bit?

I tried the 32bit version, but with that, the `phpinfo()` does not show me anything.

EDIT: There is an alternative download location [here](http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/ImageMagick/binaries/).

Comment: Thanks for providing alternative download location. You just saved me from wasting time trying to find the solution. How did you find the link, by the way? @Vadim

Comment: @rpgs_player I noticed there are broken links in a bunch of questions. So I googled the file name and found another FTP.

Answer (score 0):

I started a thread on the Imagick forum, and now I don't know, should I cry or should I laugh...

The answer for my question was this:

> Hmm... it seems we don't build our libraries with 'deprecated' methods. I will see if we can change this before the next release so DrawAllocateWand will not suddenly be gone.

I tell to the guy, ok, it's a cool thing, but I've just reinstall my machine from the scratch, so, I got this error:

```
Procedure entry point (DrawAllocateWand) not found in DLL
```

or something similar, I translated it.

So, please tell me, where can I download the `ImageMagick 6.9.1-2 Q16 x64 2015-04-14` binaries, because it seems, that `php_imagick.dll` need this, and I should work...

The answer was:

> We don't keep an archive of old binary version of ImageMagick. You could however decide to build IM from source.

**CONCLUSION**

If you ever had a working installer for windows for Apache, PHP, Imagick, you should always keep these in the cloud for yourself. MHO: I really hate these things. I know, most of us is working on linux boxes, but our company policy is to use OS what admin says. So I need to use windows. Now I should suck for a while, to download and install a cygwin with compilers, compile the Imagick somehow, and set all the environments variables, because some developers do not use a version controller, or maybe the sotrage is too expensive for them to store old binaries... I can not imagene these options.

Comment: You started a thread on the ImageMagick forum not the IMagick community. IMagick is not maintained by the people who work on ImageMagick. You can see who maintain that here: https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick

Comment: Thank you for your correction, I will update my answer.

Comment: I completely understand your frustration. I will modify our installers this week to make sure we build with 'deprecated methods' enabled. And for your information, you can build IM with VisualStudio on Windows. You don't need cygwin.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I think, cygwin is much more faster. I just wondering, why they do not keep the old binaries.

Comment: Great, there are no 6.9.1-2 Q16, or any ...1-2.. src at ftp://ftp.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/releases/

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick is available here:
http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps/

Imagick, that has been compiled against that version of ImageMagick is available here
http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/3.4.0rc5/

Downloading random versions of libraries from other places is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: Did you read my original post? I downloaded the latest from everything, and it does not work. Not just random. php_imagic.dll tells exactly the exe what I should download.