# How to use blob in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, blob

I'm new to PHP. How I can use blob in CodeIgniter? What is the best option for sending an image from the server to a client (RESTful) using codeigniter?
I have tried the following:

```
$newPerson = new Person();
$newPerson->id = 1;
$newPerson->firstName = "Qutfullo";
$newPerson->lastName = "Ochilov";
$image=new Imagick();
$image->setImage("my.jpg");
$newPerson->image=$image->getImageBlob();
$this->response($newPerson);
```

But I get an exception:

Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found.

Thanks for help!

Comment: You would use it the same way as you would without CodeIgniter. Are you working with some code that doesn't work? It would be helpful to see that code, otherwise this question is just far too broad for this site.

Comment: this is error not exception? try to include Class 'Imagick' might be missing in php libraray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope below snippet can give you the idea that you are missing library --

Try below code if on ubuntu --

```
php -m | grep imagick.
```

If the result is empty then issue below commands from terminal

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge php5-imagick && sudo apt-get install php5-imagick
```

---

if on window sserver follow below link instructions that might be useful

[Install Imagick for PHP and Apache on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27193631/installing-imagick-for-php-5-6-3-an%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bd-apache-2-4-on-win-7)

Answer (score 1):

The error is because of your server have no `Image Magic Software suite`. First you install it in your server.

For install Image Magic in Unix/Linux

```
Download ImageMagick.tar.gz from www.imagemagick.org
```

Unpack the distribution with this command:

```
tar xvzf ImageMagick.tar.gz
```

Next configure and compile ImageMagick:

```
cd ImageMagick-6.9.3
 ./configure
 make
```

To install, type

```
sudo make install
```

You may need to configure the dynamic linker run-time bindings:

```
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib
```

Install from Windows Source

```
Download ImageMagick-windows.zip from www.imagemagick.org

Unzip and Install

unzip ImageMagick-windows.zip
```

Please refer this [link](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php) for installation.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11852481)

Comment: @VinothKrishnan :Agree with you and did editing on my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a RESTFull API, The best way is to send the image URL as the response.