# Most stable ImageMagick and php_imagick.dll combination for PHP 5.6?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

This might be a Superuser question, but I've seen other installation question here, so:

I am running PHP 5.6.23 on Apache 2.4.23, VC11, x86 - to mimic my host's environment. Now I'm trying to get Imagick to run and the latest versions (ImageMagick 7.0.2-5 x86 and Imagick 3.4.3 RC1 VC11 x86 for PHP 5.6) are not working. PHP returns "The specified module could not be found" to Apache's error log. I'm not sure what compiler version applies to ImageMagick, I'm using the latest binaries from their website.

What is the most stable combination of versions of ImageMagick and Imagick to use for PHP 5.6?

Comment: This helps? http://stackoverflow.com/a/30295211/2265487 If not, to mimic the host conside a virtual machine or Docker container, here: https://hub.docker.com/_/php/ container "php:5.6.23-apache" runs apache "2.4.10-10+deb8u4". And this one httpd:2.4.23 can install "php5 (5.6.24+dfsg-0+deb8u1"

Comment: I am currently working through that article but I'm stuck at Step 6 - I just cannot get php_imagick.dll to work, regardless of version.

Comment: Try asking for advice with a comment on the answer provided, they might help you out.

Comment: This worked: [php - step-by-step instructions for installing IMAGEMAGICK on WAMP?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28872879/863165)