# ImageImagick Supported Format No Value in Xampp

Tags: php, pdf, imagick

Please help me, my imagick have no value of supported format. I install imagick in my computer for convert pdf to image.

**My environment:**

- **System**   Windows NT ACER-PC 6.1 build 7601 (Windows 7 Ultimate Edition Service Pack 1) i586
- **Compiler**     MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012)
- **Architecture**     x86
- **PHP Version 5.6.8**
- imagick module version   3.4.3RC1 (Latest Version from https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick)
- ImageMagick-7.0.3-0-Q16-x86-dll.exe (Latest Version from [Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php))

I have copy **php_imagick.dll** to c:\xampp\php\ext, copy file **CORE_RL_*.dll** to c:\xampp\apache\bin And i install ImageImagick.exe to c:\image\ and i copy file from c:\image\modules\coders*.dll to c:\xampp\apache\bin
When restart Apache, the result remains the same (Supported format no value).
Then i install Ghostscript (gs909w32). I running a simple script.

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$image = new Imagick(__DIR__.'/image.jpg');
$image->thumbnailImage(100, 100);
echo $image;
?>
```

Result : Contain Error, cannot display image.
Please help, where my mistake. Thank's before.

Comment: You have to match the version of PHP (NTS/TS and x86/x64) + PCL extension + imagick version. Follow my guide here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27193631/installing-imagick-for-php-5-6-3-and-apache-2-4-on-win-7/30295211#30295211