# Problem installing Imagick on Windows and XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp, imagick

PHP Warning:  Version warning: Imagick was compiled against ImageMagick version 1799 but version 1802 is loaded. Imagick will run but may behave surprisingly in Unknown on line 0

Comment: You can check our this link, I think it solved the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27193631/install-imagick-for-php-and-apache-on-windows

Comment: The answer is in your question. You need the correct combination of Imagemagick, Imagick and php otherwise it will not work. Even then it may not work.

Answer (score 11):

write the next line in your php.ini file

```
imagick.skip_version_check=true
```

it worked for me

**Reference**

[code grepper](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/php/PHP+Warning%3A++Version+warning%3A+Imagick+was+compiled+against+ImageMagick+version+1799+but+version+1803+is+loaded.+Imagick+will+run+but+may+behave+surprisingly+in+Unknown+on+line+0)

Answer (score 4):

Try to use this version `ImageMagick-7.0.7-25-Q16-x64-dll.exe`

you can download from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/imagemagick/files/im7-exes/

It's because the version that you installed from https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows is different from https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps/, so you need to downgrade the version to `ImageMagick-7.0.7-25-Q16-x64-dll.exe`

*NB: make sure that you using x86 or x64*

Comment: It didn't work, I tried both the versions

Comment: actually, it's work for me with the same warning info. 
PHP 7.4.11 (cli), ImageMagick 7.0.7-25 Q16 x64 2018-03-04