# Class 'imagick' not found, although phpinfo() tells different

Tags: php, imagick, wamp64

First! I know, there are many posts with this issue, I've read them all and got also any further.

I have the error message class 'imagick' not found, I reinstalled it several times, and think, I got ther right versions.

What I did:

I checked the phpinfo as described, my system looks like follows:

[image: php7.1.9]

I use wamp64.

I filled the extension in and it seems it will be loaded:

here is my phpinfo()
[image]

If I start this default script:

```
  if (!extension_loaded('Imagick')) {
        echo "nicht geladen";
  }
 else {
    echo "geladen";
}
```

It tells me, the dll is not loaded.

So whats wrong? Any help appreciated, it is quite depressing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal error: Class 'imagick' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23026181/fatal-error-class-imagick-not-found)

Comment: Are you using the php CLI or running it using apache/nginx(fpm)

Comment: @FouedMoussi. I read your suggested post before asking the question, but it hab no effekt.

Comment: MaartenDev I'm using the CLI Version