# I can't install imagick on my wampserver locally to treat background images

Tags: php

I have issues with imagick on php.
Actually i have wampserver installed with php7.3.21 x64 and thread safe. I would like to install imagick on my php through manual install.

I've tried several methods. But it doesn't work. I downloaded imagick for php.

1/ I first extracted core, im_mod and filter_ dlls that were in the bin folder to the php7.3 root folder. Then I extracted php_imagick.dll to the php7.3 ext folder. Added the extension line in the php.ini file. And class Imagick was not found. Of course i restarted the services before everything.

2/ Then i extracted the core, im_mod and filter dlls to the apache main directory. Even that didn't work.

3/ I downloaded an older version and tried and it didn'T work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be the mistake between Thread Safe and Non Thread Safe versions. Please double-check about this.

Did you try the binary from this site: https://mlocati.github.io/articles/php-windows-imagick.html

Answer (score 0):

No. My php says thread safety enabled.
This thing is really annoying me. It doesn't work.
Still tells meclass Imagick not found

It finally worked thanks to this answer below. I had to install imagick

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52731379/17789564