# How to fix Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Imagick' not found in [Directory] lib/htm.php on line 558

Tags: php, image, imagick

I have a project to make a Miiverse clone in 24 hours
and i have a problem when i want to sign in
the problem is related to images (i think)
here is the code i use :

```
$imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($filename));

    $format = $imagick->getImageFormat();
    if ($format == 'GIF') {
        $imagick = $imagick->coalesceImages();
        do {
            $imagick->scaleImage($width, $height);
        } while ($imagick->nextImage());
        $imagick = $imagick->deconstructImages();
    } else {
        $imagick->scaleImage($width, $height);
    }

    $resized = $imagick->getImagesBlob();
}

$get_keys = $dbc->prepare('SELECT * FROM cloudinary_keys ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
$get_keys->execute();
$key_result = $get_keys->get_result();
$keys = $key_result->fetch_assoc();
```

Please help me i started PHP a few months ago
Thanks for responding !
Aymo

I tried to remove the problem line but i caused more errors and i expected to repair the problem

Comment: You don't have `Imagick` defined. The error message should be in the question body in the future, not the title. Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23026181/fatal-error-class-imagick-not-found to verify you have the library?

Comment: What happens when you remove the \ before `Imagick`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just reiterating what user3783243 says above. If you install the module that error will go away.

see https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
pecl install imagick
```

If you don't have `pecl`, you need to tell us your operating system and/or Linux distribution.